# Is CapeDwarf compatible with Python GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, capedwarf

I'm trying to deploy my GAE application - written with Python - on CapeDwarf  (WildFly_2.0.0.CR5).
But all the documentation talking only about Java Application.
So is CapeDwarf can deploy Python Application ?
if it is, how to do it ?
else any other application that can ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CapeDwarf, by design, only supports Java [*] -- the author makes the point clearly in his long interview at http://www.infoq.com/articles/capedwarf , explaining the difference with other (larger but thereby inevitably more complicated) GAE implementations such as [AppScale](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale) and [TyphoonAE](https://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/) which **do** (strive to) support all programming languages GAE does (which answers your "any other application" other question:-).

[*] or presumably other languages running on the JVM, including Jython:-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Alex posted - CapeDwarf is Java only.